# Find Object Value in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

i am really new at mongodb, and i am using pymongo. So, here is my database on mongo db

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"id"},
"password":"password",
"name":"admin",
"databasedata":object
 {"vdrive":"{vdrive}"}}
```

and my question is, cant i find the vdrive value using the _id ?
im using this code:

```
users = mongo.db.exampledb

(users.find_one({'databasedata': 'vdrive'}))
```

but it return None. I really appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: See [Getting a Single Document With find_one()](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html?highlight=find_one#getting-a-single-document-with-find-one) in PyMongo and in `mongo` shell [db.collection.findOne()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/index.html). In the docs the _projection_ specifies the field(s) to return. The projection can be applied to scalar field types like string, number, etc., and composite fields like arrays and sub-documents (or objects).

Answer (score 0):

[`find_one()`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) requires a filter and a projection.

> using the _id

To filter on the `_id` field the filter needs to specify `_id`.

> find the vdrive value

To find this value the projection needs to use the dot notation because vdrive is an embedded object.

So you will need something like:

```
db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
db.users.find_one({'_id': <ID_YOU_WANT_TO_FILTER_ON>}, {'databasedata.vdrive': 1})
```